# Deriving the normalizing constant of the Wishart Distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, probability-distributions, matrix-calculus

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$I'm reading [Matrix Algebra (2007)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387708723) by Gentle, and one of the problems given was to find the normalizing constant of the Wishart distribution, with the probability density of the Wishart distribution proportional to $e^{\tr(-\Sigma^{-1}W/2)}|W|^{(n-d-1)/2}$. In this case, $\Sigma$ is a fixed symmetric positive definite matrix of size $d \times d$, and $W$ is a $d \times d$ positive semi-definite matrix. $n$ is a positive parameter, and $|W|$ is the determinant of $W$.

The normalizing constant is $2^{dn/2}\Gamma_d(\frac{1}{2})|\Sigma|^{n/2}$, where $\Gamma_d(x)$ is the multivariate gamma function. However, I'm not sure how to show that. A hint given was to use the change of variables $W = 2\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} Y \Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

I believe my main problem is that I'm unfamiliar with the formula to use for the change of variables in this case, where the integration variable is a matrix. Using the suggested change of variable of $W$ to $Y,$ and taking the integral over $D$, the set of all positive definite matrices, I get:

\begin{align*}
& \int_D e^{\tr(-\Sigma^{-1}W/2)}|W|^{(n-d-1)/2} \, dW \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_D e^{-\tr(Y)}|2\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}Y\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}|^{(n-d-1)/2} (??) \, dY\\[8pt]
= {} & 2^{d(n-d-1)/2} |\Sigma|^{(n-d-1)/2} (??) \int_D e^{-\tr(Y)}|Y|^{(n-d-1)/2} \,dY\\[8pt]
= {} & 2^{d(n-d-1)/2} |\Sigma|^{(n-d-1)/2} (??) \Gamma_d \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

In the above, I assume the (??) is the determinant of some Jacobian? My initial thought was that it would be equal to $|2\Sigma|^d$, but it does not lead to the correct answer. I'm quite new to linear algebra and matrix calculus, so I'm not sure where I went wrong, any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this problem boils down to is knowing that
$$\begin{align}
\lvert GXG^{\mathsf{T}}\rvert&=\lvert GG^{\mathsf{T}}\rvert\lvert X\rvert\\
\mathrm{d}(GXG^{\mathsf{T}})&=\lvert GG^{\mathsf{T}}\rvert^{(d+1)/2}\mathrm{d}X
\end{align}$$

and thus that the measure
$$\mathrm{d}_*X\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\frac{\mathrm{d} X}{\lvert X\rvert^{(d+1)/2}}$$
does not vary under transformations $X\to GXG^{\mathsf{T}}$, whence

$$\frac{1}{\lvert K\rvert^{s}}=\frac{\int_D \mathrm{e}^{-(K,X)} \lvert X \rvert^s \, \mathrm{d}_*X}{\int_D \mathrm{e}^{-\operatorname{Tr} X} \lvert X \rvert^s \, \mathrm{d}_*X}.$$

---

Addendum

There are a few ways to get the cited results. You can

- use the $LDL^{\mathsf{T}}$ Cholesky factorization, as in [Gross and Richards (1987)](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1987-301-02/S0002-9947-1987-0882715-2/S0002-9947-1987-0882715-2.pdf) (they call it a "bitriangular structure"), or
- write $G=\mathrm{e}^{tA}$ and show that the rate of change of $\mathrm{d}X$ with respect to $t$ is $\tfrac{d+1}{2}(A+A^{\mathsf{T}})\mathrm{d}X$, or
- use results from the theory of functions on a Euclidean Jordan algebra. This is the modern, "highbrow" approach.

Comment: How do I get that $d(GXG^{\mathsf{T}}) = \lvert GG^{\mathsf{T}}\rvert^{(d+1)/2}\mathrm{d}X$? Is this somewhat related to a matrix-by-matrix derivative like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834355/matrix-by-matrix-derivative-formula

Comment: added to answer

Comment: Thanks! Will look into those.