# Derivative of $L^{-1}xx^TL^{-1}$ wrt L

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I wish to find the derivative $L^{-1}xx^TL^{-1}$ with respect to the symmetric positive definite matrix $L$, and $x$ is a vector. How do I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1834355/339790)

Comment: What kind of derivative?  A Jacobian-like thing would be 4-dimensional

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\E{{\cal E}}  \def\d{\delta}  \def\L{L^{-1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}  \def\k{\otimes}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Given the symmetric matrix-valued function
$$\eqalign{
F &= \L xx^T\L \;\doteq\; F^T \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad
}$$
calculate its differential with respect to $L$ (which is also symmetric)
$$\eqalign{
dF &= \CLR{d\L}xx^T\L + \L xx^T\CLR{d\L} \\
 &= \CLR{-\L\,dL\:\L}xx^T\L + \L xx^T\CLR{-\L\,dL\:\L} \\
 &= -\LR{\L\,dL\:F + F\:dL\:\L} \\
}$$
[Vectorize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) this expression and rearrange it into a matrix-valued gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\ell &= \vc{dL} \\
df &= \vc{dF} \;=\; -\LR{F\k\L + \L\k F} d\ell \\
\grad{f}{\ell} &= -\LR{F\k\L + \L\k F} \\\\
}$$
Another approach is to introduce the fourth-order identity tensor $\E$ with
components
$$\eqalign{
\E_{ijkl} = \grad{L_{ij}}{L_{kl}} \;=\; \d_{ik}\,\d_{jl}
}$$
and calculate a tensor-valued gradient
$$\eqalign{
dF &= -\LR{\L\E F + F\E\L}:dL \\
\grad{F}{L} &= -\LR{\L\E F + F\E\L} \\\\
}$$
Yet another approach is to write the differential using *index notation*. 
This yields the scalar components of the gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad{F_{ij}}{L_{kl}} &= -\LR{\L_{ik}F_{jl} + F_{ik}\L_{jl}} \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the derivative of $g(L)=L^{-1}$ is the linear function $Δ↦ -L^{-1}ΔL^{-1}$, which follows from

$$\begin{aligned} 
g(L+Δ) &= (L+{Δ})^{-1}
\\&= (L(+L^{-1}{Δ})^{-1} 
\\&= (+L^{-1}{Δ})^{-1}L^{-1}
\\&= \big( - L^{-1}{Δ} + (‖Δ‖²)\big) L^{-1}  \qquad\text{(Neumann Series)}
\\&= g(L) - L^{-1} {Δ} L^{-1} + (‖Δ‖²)
\end{aligned}$$

Consider the function $f(L) = L^{-1} xx^⊤ L^{-1}$, then

$$\begin{aligned}
f(L+Δ) &= (L+{Δ})^{-1}xx^⊤(L+Δ)^{-1}
\\&= (L^{-1} - L^{-1}ΔL^{-1} + (‖Δ‖^2))xx^⊤(L^{-1} - L^{-1}ΔL^{-1} + (‖Δ‖^2))
\\&= f(L) - L^{-1}ΔL^{-1}xx^⊤L^{-1} - L^{-1}xx^⊤L^{-1}ΔL^{-1} +(‖Δ‖^2) 
\end{aligned}$$

Hence, the derivative of $f$ at $L$ is the linear function $$\boxed{Δ ⟼ - L^{-1}ΔL^{-1}xx^⊤L^{-1} - L^{-1}xx^⊤L^{-1}ΔL^{-1}}$$

---

This function can be represented as a 4d-tensor, using the formula $AXB^⊤ = (A⊗B)⋅X$, $^{(*)}$ where $(A⊗B)_{ij, kl} ≕ A_{ik}B_{jl}$ is a 4d tensor and $(A⊗B)⋅X ≕ ∑_{kl}(A⊗B)_{ij, kl}X_{kl}$ is a 2d tensor contraction. Using the symmetry of $L$ we have:

$$\begin{align}
f(L) &= [Δ⟼- L^{-1}ΔL^{-1}xx^⊤L^{-1} - L^{-1}xx^⊤L^{-1}ΔL^{-1}] &&∈ \text{Lin}(ℝ^{n×n},ℝ^{n×n})
\\&≅ - L^{-1}⊗L^{-1}xx^⊤L^{-1} - L^{-1}xx^⊤L^{-1}⊗L^{-1} &&∈ ℝ^{n×n}⊗(ℝ^{n×n})^*
\end{align}$$

(*): Note that one of the linked posts has $ = (B^⊤⊗A)X$, this is just a result of different convention on how $⊗$ is defined.