# How to calculate a vec-permutation matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, biology

I'm trying to follow the maths in a paper on modelling population dynamics and have come unstuck on the calculation of the vec-permutation matrix.

Let $p$ be the number of patches and $s$ be the number of stages. For my example, both $s$ and $p$ are $= 2$.

The vec-permutation matrix has dimension $(sp × sp)$ and is given by:

$P(s,p) = \sum_{i=1}^{s}\sum_{j=1}^{p}E_{ij}\otimes E_{ij}^T$

The authors state $E_{ij}$ is an $s × p$ matrix with a $1$ in the $(i, j)$
position and zeros elsewhere and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker
matrix product.

From the paper, it should be the $4$ x $4$ matrix:

$P(2,2)= \begin{pmatrix}
1  & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $

I don't understand the $E_{ij}$ matrix. I thought every matrix position could be considered $ij$.

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Christine_Hunter5/publication/228754096_The_use_of_the_vec-permutation_matrix_in_spatial_matrix_population_models/links/5551497808ae956a5d25ed48.pdf

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.  As you say, *The authors state $E_{ij}$ is an $s × p$ matrix with a $1$ in the $(i, j)$
position and zeros elsewhere*.  So, we know what $E_{ij}$ is supposed to mean.  What's the problem?

Comment: So, in the $2 \times 2$ case for example, 
$$
E_{12} = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$

Comment: Even with that definition, I don't understand what that matrix looks like. Like I said I thought the (i,j) position covers all of the elements of a matrix.

Comment: I have no idea what that sentence means: "I thought the (i,j) position covers all elements of a matrix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe looking at the $3 \times 3$ case will be helpful.  Note that
$$
\sum_{i,j} E_{ij} \otimes E_{ij} = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc}
1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
If we take the transpose of each $3 \times 3$ block, we get the desired matrix
$$
\sum_{i,j} E_{ij} \otimes E_{ij}^T = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc}
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
\hline
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
\hline
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: That was very helpful. I did not know how you built up the individual $E_{ij}$ matrices.

Comment: If I have answered this question to your satisfaction, please accept the answer by clicking the $\checkmark$.

Comment: Thanks, I was reading the exact same paper, and wondering the exact same thing.

Comment: @Roasty247 I'm glad you found it helpful. You might also find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307299/81360) to be useful.