# How to differentiate a matrix equation w.r.t a vector?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I have a matrix equation that yields a scalar

$$f(M) = MAM^T - 2 \sum_i^{N} \log(M_i)$$

Where $M$ is a $1 \times N$ row vector, and $A$ is an $N \times N$ matrix. As such, the result $f$ is a scalar.

How does one take the derivative of $f$ w.r.t $M$? I have seen [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) define derivatives of matrices w.r.t specific index values, but I couldn't find a definition of differentiation w.r.t vectors.

My intuition is something like

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial M} = 2(AM - M^{\circ -1})$$

with my reasoning being the two $M$'s in the first term yield $2AM$ once differentiated, and the log term yields $M$ where each element is raised to the $-1$ power ($\frac{d \log x}{dx} = x^{-1}$).

Again, I'm not sure if I've done this correctly, and the fact that $f$ is a scalar makes it a bit more confusing.

Comment: What is $M_i \,$?

Comment: I think instead of $2AM$ you want $AM+A^T M$, unless you know that A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Since $M$ is a row vector, the product $AM$ _does not exist_. However, if you change that term to $MA$ then your result is correct (assuming that $A$ is symmetric).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We    use  the linearity of differentiation and consider at   first
\begin{align*}
g(M)=MAM^T\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with $M=(M_i)_{1\leq i\leq N}$ an $(1\times N)$-matrix.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> dg(M)&=dMAM^T+MAdM^T\tag{2}\\
> \mathrm{vec}(dg(M))&=\mathrm{vec}(dMAM^T)+\mathrm{vec}(MAdM^T)\tag{3}\\
> &=\left(MA^T\otimes  I_1\right)\mathrm{vec}(dM)+\left(I_1\otimes   MA\right)\mathrm{vec}\left(dM^T\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=MA^T\mathrm{vec}(dM)+MA I_n\mathrm{vec}(dM)\tag{5}\\
> &=\left(MA^T+MA\right)\mathrm{vec}(dM)\\
> \color{blue}{\frac{\partial g(M)}{dM}}&=\frac{\partial \mathrm{vec}(dg(M))}{\mathrm{vec}(dM)}=\color{blue}{M\left(A^T+A\right)}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we start by calculating the differential.
- In (3) we *[vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))* the equation.
- In (4) we use the relationship with *[Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products)* to factor out $\mathrm{vec}(dM)$ resp. $\mathrm{vec}(dM^T)$.
- In (5) we do a simplification and use $\mathrm{vec}(dM^T)=C\mathrm{vec}(dM)$ by noting  the *[commutation matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307299)* $C=I_n$.
- In (6) we take the gradient.

> We can check the result (6) by setting
>
> \begin{align*}
> g(M)&=MAM^T\\
> &=\left(M_i\right)_{1\leq i\leq N}\left(A_{ij}\right)_{1\leq i,j\leq N}\left(M_i\right)^T_{1\leq i\leq N}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{j=1}^N M_jA_{ij}\right)_{1\leq i\leq N}\left(M_i\right)^T_{1\leq i\leq N}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N  M_iM_jA_{ij}
> \end{align*}

We obtain

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial  g(M)}{\partial M}}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial\left(M_1,\ldots,M_N\right)}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^NM_iM_jA_{ij}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial M_k}\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N M_iM_jA_{ij}\right)_{1\leq k\leq N}\\
&=\left(\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\ne  k}}^N  M_jA_{kj}+\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\ne k}}^NM_iA_{ik}+2M_kA_{kk}\right)_{1\leq k\leq N}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\sum_{j=1}^NM_j\left(A_{kj}+A_{jk}\right)\right)_{1\leq k\leq N}}
\end{align*}

in accordance with (6).

> Finally considering $f$ we obtain using (6)
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial f(M)}{\partial M}&=M\left(A^T+A\right)-2\frac{\partial}{\partial (M_1,\ldots,M_N)}\sum_{i=1}^N\log(M_i)\\
> &=M\left(A^T+A\right)-2\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial    M_k}\sum_{i=1}^N\log(M_i)\right)_{1\leq    k\leq N}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=M\left(A^T+A\right)-2\left(\frac{1}{M_k}\right)_{1\leq k\leq N}}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

You can think of $f$ as a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$. Then if $u\in\mathbb R^n$,$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\nabla f\cdot u=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\\vdots\\u_n\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{k}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}u_k.$$In particular, define $f:\mathbb R^{1\times n}\to\mathbb R$ by$$M\mapsto MAM^T-2\sum_k\log(M_k),$$where $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Then, if $N\in\mathbb R^{1\times n}$,$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial N}(M)=(M(A+A^T)-2M^{\circ-1})\cdot N.$$

Note that if $A$ is symmetric,$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial N}(M)=2(MA-M^{\circ-1})\cdot N.$$

Comment: What is $N$? It doesn't appear in the question and it isn't defined in your answer.

Comment: $N$ is a direction in which to compute the derivative of $f$, so that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial N}(M)$ is the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $M$ in the direction of $N$.