# Kronecker product between matrices

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

I have to proove that $(K_{p,p}⊗ I_p)(\vec{a}⊗\vec{a}⊗\vec{a})$ equals $(\vec{a}⊗\vec{a}⊗\vec{a})$, where $\vec{a}$ is px1 vector, $I_p$ is unit matrix pxp and $K_{p,p}$ is commutation matrix ppxpp. I have some ideas, but I'm not sure, do I think right. I tried to proove it from right to left. Starting from $(\vec{a}⊗\vec{a}⊗\vec{a})$ = $((\vec{a}⊗\vec{a})⊗\vec{a})$

I used to fact, that $(\vec{a}⊗\vec{a})= K_{p,p} \cdot(\vec{a}⊗\vec{a}) \cdot K_{1,1}$. And I know, that commutation matrix is orthogonal, so $K_{p,p}'\cdot K_{p,p}=I_{p,p}$. So I have $K_{p,p}\cdot I_{p,p}\cdot (\vec{a}⊗\vec{a})$. But are $K_{p,p}\cdot I_{p,p}$ and $K_{p,p}⊗I_{p}$ equal?

Comment: Commutation matrix is block matrix K_{m,n} : mn x mn that has n x m blocks when (K_{m,n})_{(i,j)(g,h)} is 1 when g=j and i=h, 0 otherwise, where i,h=1,...,m and j,g=1,...,n

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to write this commutation matrix as a Kronecker product ? See interesting things [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311148/305862).

Comment: 1) As seen in the answer I have indicated you, the easiest way to work with a commutation matrix is to consider it as the operator sending $vec(A)$ onto $vec(A^T)$. 2) Besides (your last line) $K_{p,p}\cdot I_{p,p}$ and $K_{p,p}⊗I_{p}$ cannot be equal because they haven't the same dimensions.

Comment: ... unless $I_{p,p}$ mean $I_{(p^2)}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix)

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Thank you. Indeed, it is a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give a direct proof for the *particular* case $p=2$ involving matrices with dimension $p^3=8$.

Let $\mathbf{a}=\pmatrix{p\\q}$.

We have

$$b:=\mathbf{a}\otimes \mathbf{a}=\pmatrix{p^2\\pq\\pq\\q^2} \ \text{and} \
c:=(\mathbf{a}\otimes \mathbf{a})\otimes \mathbf{a}= \pmatrix{p^3\\p^2q\\p^2q\\pq^2\\p^2q\\pq^2\\pq^2\\q^3}$$

Let use apply property $$ (\mathbf{A} \otimes \mathbf{B})(\mathbf{C} \otimes \mathbf{D}) = (\mathbf{AC}) \otimes (\mathbf{BD})$$

(That you can find for example in the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) about Kronecker product) to :

$$ (\mathbf{K_{2,2}} \otimes \mathbf{I_2})((\mathbf{a}\otimes \mathbf{a}) \otimes \mathbf{a}) = (\mathbf{\mathbf{K_{2,2}} b}) \otimes (\mathbf{I_2a})$$

which can be transformed into :

$$\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1}\pmatrix{p^2\\pq\\pq\\q^2}\otimes \mathbf{a}$$

which indeed is equal to :

$$\pmatrix{p^2\\pq\\pq\\q^2}\otimes \mathbf{a}= (\mathbf{a}\otimes \mathbf{a}) \otimes \mathbf{a}$$

as desired.

---

Edit :

What have we learned from this particular example ? Look at the last relationship : the key fact (independent of dimension $p$) is that :

$$K_{p,p} (a \otimes a)= a \otimes a $$

which remains to be proven in the general case, but which is a lot simpler than the initial question.

Comment: Please note that the sum of entries of $a\otimes a\otimes a$ is $(p+q)^3$ ; it would be $(p+q+r)^3$ in the case $a=\pmatrix{p\\q\\r}$, etc.

Comment: Have a look at my Edit.

Comment: Any comment ?...